# Windows Store App httpClient json

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get a json in a C# Windows Store App. here is my code

```
client = new HttpClient(); 
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,  "http://192.168.1.105:8080/button.json");
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
```

And I get "System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"

I also tried

`System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine`

Comment: Your server is broken.  You should fix it to correctly follow HTTP. For more info, look at the request in Fiddler.

Comment: I tested with firefox poster and it works fine

Comment: That means that Firefox is more accepting of broken servers.  Use Fiddler to find the problem.